# Program that finds the largest prime factor

Tags: c#, math, prime-factoring

So I wrote a code for finding the largest factor for my learning procces on Project Euler and it worked fine and I got the right answer. Tho I saw diffrent solutions and they were "longer" and looked more complicated. So my question is, is there anything my code is no taking care of for lets say different number or is there a better way to do this task? I am trying to learn different ways of solving problems to get better at programming so I wonder if I should have done that code in a different way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace prime_factor
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long n = 600851475143;
        int largest = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if (n%i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                n /= i;
                largest = i;

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(largest);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you try it with 8, you get 4, do you not? Your program doesn't return prime factors.

Comment: Oh yea. You are right. It is finding the largest prime number, but it doesn't give me prime numbers as it should. I guess I focused on topic more than on the whole point of program. So it solved the problem but didn't write all prime numbers correctly

Comment: I think you can only iterate up to sqrt(n) and check both factors

Comment: I think the problem is that you increment i even if it was a factor. You should give each value of i a chance to divide until it fails. i.e., change your if to while.
Regarding other, more complicated solutions, don't worry about it! If you get the right answer, it means you found a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks! I found a solution I think. I changed if (n%i == 0) for while (n%i==0) so basicly it now gives a chance for every i until it fails. Am I right here? I got a correct answer for numbers like 8 and 36 now.

Comment: what about [600851475149](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133727/project-euler-3-largest-prime-factor/133785)?

Answer (score 2):

If you divide *n* by *f* every time you find a factor, you will automatically find only prime factors. Here's pseudocode that you can translate to your favorite language:

```
function factors(n)
    f := 2; fs := []
    while f * f <= n
        if n % f == 0
            fs := fs ++ f
            n := n / f
        else
            f := f + 1
    fs := fs ++ n
    return fs
```

Here *fs* is a linked list of factors, and ++ is the list-append operation. You can see a Python implementation [here](https://ideone.com/OWdmOg).

There are better ways to find factors, but this is sufficient for the *Project Euler* problem that you are trying to solve. If you are interested in programming with prime numbers, you might enjoy [this essay](https://programmingpraxis.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/primenumbers.pdf) at my blog.

Comment: I already solved this after tips from other users. But I guess Your way is more efficient. Will surely check this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like it - you get around checking if `i` is prime, which is the most complicated part! If it were not prime, you would have already divided out it's composite factors.

However, I think there are cases where a non-prime `i` can sneak in - where multiples of prime factors divide your `n`. Try `n = 36` (since 36 == 2^2 * 3^2). I think your algorithm returns 6.

You just need to add a loop to see if `i` can divide `n` multiple times and I think it will fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I think I fixed issue. So what I did I changed my if statement for while so it will be checking this statement as long as it is possible to divide. And now it worked for 36. Do You think there is any more issues?

Comment: while (n%i == 0)                                                                                                       {                                                                                                                  Console.WriteLine(i);                                                                                       n /= i;                                                                                                             largest = i;                                                                                                          }

Comment: I think this will work - even though you are not checking if `i` is prime, you have already tried to divide `n` by all lower integers. It's also very efficient, since you keep on lowering `n` as you go - I think you stumbled on a really nice algorithm!

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! That means a lot to me since I am just starting programming more. And I want to get better in understanding staff as programmer and be able to code and help other just like U helped me! Thanks!

Comment: I did! But it doesn't show since I dont have over 15 reputation.